# How to get component variable in ag grid scope

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

```
export class HospiComponent {

    countries:CountryModel[];

    constructor(public router: Router, private masterService:MasterService, private hospitalService:HospitalService) { 
        this.loadCountry();

        this.columnDefs = [
              { headerName: 'Id', field: 'hospiId', width: 75 },
              { headerName: 'Name', field: 'compaVaNameEn', width: 250 },
              { headerName: 'cotryId', field: 'orgsmId', width: 100, valueGetter:  countryNameGetter }
        ];

        this.defaultColDef = { resizable: true };
        this.service.getHosps().subscribe(response => {
          this.rowData = response['result'];
        })

        function countryNameGetter (params) {
            console.log(params.data.orgsmId + JSON.stringify(this.organisms));
            return this.countries.filter(item => item.cotryId === params.data.cotryId).name; // this is not working as countries is not available in this scope
        }
    }

    loadCountry(){
        this.countries = [{"cotryId":25,"name":"Russia"},{"cotryId":35,"name":"Kuwait"}];
    }
}
```

Ag grid used to display the grid data. The country name service return is ID which needs to be replaced with country name.
But `this.countries` value is not available in the grid scope. How can I get the value in grid scope?

Tried this `valueGetter: organismNameGetter.bind(this)` which is not working.

Comment: I would expect `bind(this)` to work. But you could also use an arrow function: `valueGetter: (params) => { ... }`. Arrow functions allow you to use `this` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`valueGetter` could use **`component`** context via `.bind(this)`

```
valueGetter:  this.countryNameGetter.bind(this)
```

and then `countryNameGetter` - shouldn't be a `function` inside `constructor`, it should be a `function` within `this` component

```
export class HospiComponent {
    ...
    countryNameGetter (params) {
        console.log(params.data.orgsmId + JSON.stringify(this.organisms));
        return this.countries.filter(item => item.cotryId === params.data.cotryId).name;
    }
    ...
}
```

> But you have to check the ag-grid life cycle for `valueGetter` (when it's executed), to be sure that your data is ready when it would be requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to implement the example provided by [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-more-details/#parent_child)

```
// in the parent component - the component that hosts ag-grid-angular and specifies which angular components to use in the grid
constructor() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        context: {
            componentParent: this
        }
    };
    this.gridOptions.rowData = this.createRowData();
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs();
}

// in the child component - the angular components created dynamically in the grid
// the parent component can then be accessed as follows:
this.params.context.componentParent
```

You can read more about ag-grid context [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context/)